# Using the && operator with non-boolean operands

Tags: ruby

What does the following piece of code mean, and why would someone write it like this?

```
a = 1
b = 2

if a && b != a 
   ...
end
```

What is the difference between that and just

```
if a != b
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a != b` just checks if `a` and `b` are not equal,

where as `a && b != a` checks if `a`'s truth value is `True` *and* `a` and `b` are unequal

An alternate way of representing this would be:

```
if a
    if b != a
        #Do something
```

Comment: ah, I thought `&&` had higher precedence than `==` and so was grouping it in my head as `(a && b) != a`. That makes sense.

Comment: Yeah. Since this is a boolean expression, think of it as `expression1 && expression2` : Some more info here: http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html (Boolean expressions)

Answer (score 1):

`if a` checks for `a` to be truthy (neither `nil` or `false`):

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
if a && b != a
  puts "I will be printed"
end

a = false # or nil
b = 'b'
if a && b != a
  puts "I will NOT be printed"
end
```